# How to make Audio Trimming widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I am new in flutter. I want to trim a audio. So i got the [audiocutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/audiocutter) to implement trimming But problem is that "How to get input from the user in better UI?". I was search about that but not get any proper solution. So, how to make widget like below to get input from user.

[image]

Please help me to make this widget or if you have any idea to make above widget in flutter than tell me.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I would be interested in this also.

Comment: @kaushik have you find widget like you want?

Comment: No still not get please upvote my question then may be some one help us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a widget like this.

[image]

If you want to create widget like above.
Then you can add [wave_slider](https://github.com/ChiragKothiya1996/Flutter/blob/main/wave_slider.dart) file and use following code.

```
WaveSlider(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
  heightWaveSlider: 100,
  widthWaveSlider: 300,
  duration: 12.0,
  callbackStart: (duration) {
    print("Start $duration");
  },
  callbackEnd: (duration) {
    print("End $duration");
  },
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Chirag it's more useful but past full code instead of link.