# How to make Audio Trimming widget in flutter And wave graph for sound

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am new in flutter.
I want to trim a audio.

[image: Flutter Audio Wave]

[image: Flutter Audio Wave]

I got the `audiocutter` package to implement trimming.
But problem is that "How to get input from the user in better UI?".
I searched about that, but not get any proper solution.

So, how to make widget like below to get input from user?

Comment: is any solution found?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Audio Trimming widget in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62103154/how-to-make-audio-trimming-widget-in-flutter)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You want to create widget like above.
Then you can add [wave_slider](https://github.com/ChiragKothiya1996/Flutter/blob/main/wave_slider.dart) file and use following code.

```
WaveSlider(
  backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade300,
  heightWaveSlider: 100,
  widthWaveSlider: 300,
  duration: 12.0,
  callbackStart: (duration) {
    print("Start $duration");
  },
  callbackEnd: (duration) {
    print("End $duration");
  },
)
```